# When committing, how to automatically populate Log Message dialog with merge log message from "Recent Messages"?

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN 1.8.2.

In a nutshell, my goal is to automatically generate a log message when committing merged revisions with a merge log template.

I am first creating a merge log template for my project by going to TortoiseSVN->Properties and then selecting New->Merge Log Templates. I have edited the merge title, reverse merge title, and finally the merge log message until it's in the format I want. This property is then applied to my project.

Now, when I merge a revision from another project URL and go to commit it, my Log Message dialog is empty. When I click the "Recent Messages" button above this dialog, I'm able to see the correct message as generated by the aforementioned property. Double clickling this message will populate it into the log message dialog in the exact format I expect.

How do I have the log message dialog automatically populate with the message generated by the template in "Recent Messages" without having to manually open "Recent Messages" and double click?

Basically, when I open the Commit dialog, I would like to see the log message already populated without having to do anything else.

Comment: The best way to automate svn is to use `svn` directly from command line, and not use TortoiseSVN.